# Fullcalendar get currently visible / scroll time

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I somehow want to listen to scroll events on the Fullcalendar (version 5) to get the current `scrollTime`. This would allow me to jump to that time with `scrollToTime()` when coming back from an other page in my app.

My current approach is to add a native JS scroll-listener like this and somehow get the current start time visible:

```js
const fcScroller = document.getElementsByClassName('fc-scroller')[1];
    
fcScroller.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
   console.log(this.$refs.fullCalendar);
});
```

The listener in general is working just fine, but how do I get the currently visible time from Fullcalendar?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such ability. Maybe you should make a feature request

Comment: I just found this request: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5736